# GNU Screen -- horizontal scrolling

Tags: linux, unix, gnu-screen

I've been trying to figure this out -- the goal is to scroll horizontally in GNU Screen. (In order to avoid ugly line wrap in the result of CLI mysql queries.)

If you do:

```
screen -h 5000 # 5000 lines history
Ctrl-a r # to disable horizontal wrap
mysql -u user -p
SELECT * FROM db.big_fat_table LIMIT 500;
Ctrl-a [ # to enter scroll (copy) mode
```

Now you can scroll up and down with `Ctrl-b` and `Ctrl-d`, respectively. But how do you scroll right and left?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think turning the `wrap` option off does what you think it does. Here's what my man page shows for the `wrap` option:

> ```
> wrap [on|off]
>
> Sets  the  line-wrap setting for the current window.  When line-wrap is
> on, the second consecutive printable character output at the last  col-
> umn  of  a  line  will  wrap to the start of the following line.  As an
> added feature, backspace (^H) will also wrap through the left margin to
> the previous line.  Default is ‘on’.
> ```

This is a low-level terminal feature and isn't related to horizontal scrolling.

However, `less` has a feature that might help you, the `-S` switch allows you to scroll left and right within a file using the left and right arrow keys. If you're viewing a result file with long lines, this can be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know screen doesn't do horizontal scrolling. Screen mostly emulates a hardware terminal, and horizontal scrolling is not a typical feature of hardware terminals.

You could run your queries in a `M-x shell` buffer in Emacs. The `truncate-lines` variable controls whether long lines are wrapped or not. When long lines are not wrapped, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd><</kbd> scrolls left and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>></kbd> scrolls right.